# Замена символов на буквы

Tags: c#, массивы, linq, char

Есть программа,которая должна выводить слово,где буквы заменены на символ '_' и пользователь по 1 букве угадывает этого слово.  Проблема в том,что программа выводит только 1 букву и заменяется тоже только по одной и после ввода слова по буквам не прекращает работать. Помогите найти ошибку.

```
        string[] slovo = new string [] {"algoritm"};
        char[] guess = new char[slovo.Length];

        for (int p = 0; p < slovo.Length; p++)

            guess[p] = '_';

        while(true)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(guess);

            char bukva = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int j=0; j < slovo.Length; j++)

            {

                if (slovo[j].Contains(bukva))

                    guess[j] = bukva;

                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Takoj bukvi net!");

            }


      }
```

Comment: Просто воспользуйтесь отладчиком

Comment: `string[] slovo = new string [] {"algoritm"};` - почему массив? соответственно `for (int p = 0; p < slovo.Length; p++)` - цикл от 0 до 0

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string slovo = "algoritm"; // Ваше слово
            string guess = "________"; // Ваш ответ
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(guess); // Для изменения букв по индексу

            while(true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(guess); // Выводим ваш ответ
                char bukva = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()); // Считываем букву
                for (int i = 0; i < slovo.Length; i++) // Лучше использовать массив, т.к. Contains показывает лишь 1 вхождение, а таких букв в слове может быть больше
                {
                    if (slovo[i] == bukva) 
                    {
                        sb[i] = bukva; // Если есть совпадение, заменяем '_' на эту букву
                    }
                    guess = sb.ToString(); // Приводим наш объект StringBuilder  к типу String для WriteLine при следующей итерации
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, условие выхода из программы допишете сами.
Также не забудьте вставить `using System.Text` для работы с `StringBuilder`.

**UPDATE**

Если вы решили использовать имя переменной `guess`, соблюдайте то же для других имен. Прим. вместо `slovo` используйте `word`. Не очень хорошая практика давать такие разные названия.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string slovo = "algoritm";
        char[] guess = new char[slovo.Length];

        for (int p = 0; p < guess.Length; p++)
            guess[p] = '_';

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(guess);

            string bukva2 = Console.ReadLine();
            char bukva = ' ';

            if (bukva2.Length == 1) 
            bukva = Convert.ToChar(bukva2);

            bool EstBukva = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < slovo.Length; j++)
            {
                if (slovo[j] == bukva)
                {
                    guess[j] = bukva;
                    EstBukva = true;
                }

            }
            if (!EstBukva)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Takoj bukvi net!");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }
```

Я бы сделал так

Comment: А что означает условие if(!EstBukva)? Это условие для того случая,если значение остается false?

Comment: да, именно для этого